# Network problems after system reboot - Ubuntu 18.04 Server

Tags: networking, dns, networkmanager, resolv.conf, systemd-resolved

I have a problem with one of my Ubuntu 18.04 servers.

After a recent power cut, I can no longer connect to it from outside the network.

I'm currently SSHing to it through another server in my network (which does have internet access).

```
ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

 ping -c4 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3050ms



cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

Pinging my router (192.168.1.1) works, but is actually quite slow, and intermittantly hangs:

```
 ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=1.81 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=1.67 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=1.85 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=3.80 ms
```

And also, sometimes (maybe one in every 10 attempts) a ping to google.com returns the following:

```
ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.169.78) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lhr48s09-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.169.78): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=24.6 ms
64 bytes from lhr48s09-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.169.78): icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=19.2 ms
64 bytes from lhr48s09-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.169.78): icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=14.8 ms
64 bytes from lhr48s09-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.169.78): icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=25.7 ms
64 bytes from lhr48s09-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.169.78): icmp_seq=5 ttl=55 time=57.0 ms
64 bytes from lhr48s09-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.169.78): icmp_seq=6 ttl=55 time=21.9 ms
64 bytes from lhr48s09-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.169.78): icmp_seq=7 ttl=55 time=16.6 ms
```

I've disabled resolvd:

```
 systemctl status systemd-resolved.service
● systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
           https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/resolved
           https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
           https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
```

And, following some advice from another forum,  added an entry to `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-systemd-resolved.conf`  to ensure Network manager is ignoring resolvd.

The last time the system rebooted (about 3 weeks ago), it recovered with no network related problems at all.  There have been no updates to the server in that time.

If I take a look a look at the configuration of another Linux machine on the network (in this case, a Rasberry Pi,) I can see it's successfully using resolvd:

```
pi@colin:~ $ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::1
```

I have tried adding nameserver 8.8.8.8 to the resolv.conf of the problematic server but this makes no difference.

### EDIT

Strangely, I can ping external DNS servers, albeit very slowly.  For example:

```
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=58 time=15.1 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=98 ttl=58 time=18.2 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=99 ttl=58 time=15.6 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=100 ttl=58 time=12.4 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=101 ttl=58 time=9.09 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=102 ttl=58 time=22.3 ms
...
<approx 40 second pause>
...
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=103 ttl=58 time=16.5 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=104 ttl=58 time=24.9 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=105 ttl=58 time=12.3 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=144 ttl=58 time=13.9 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=145 ttl=58 time=28.4 ms
...
<approx 10 second pause>
...
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=146 ttl=58 time=8.77 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=147 ttl=58 time=9.13 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=148 ttl=58 time=22.3 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=149 ttl=58 time=25.4 ms
...
<approx 20 second pause>
...
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=190 ttl=58 time=9.26 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=191 ttl=58 time=15.9 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=192 ttl=58 time=12.7 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=235 ttl=58 time=14.8 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=236 ttl=58 time=19.7 ms
```

There seems to be no consistency to the ping response times.

Comment: In your resolv.conf, make sure `8.8.8.8` is listed as a nameserver, before `192.168.1.1` and that ipv6 address you mentioned. In that case, can you reproduce those slow responses/dns resolution inconsistencies? If not, it sounds like the DNS server on `192.168.1.1` is somehow responsible.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up bouncing the router and that sorted the issue.  Not something I could do remotely.  Very strange problem and a hard reboot of a router seemed unnecessary but unavoidable at that point.